# Is there any good reason to merge a short-term, tagged change in the software?

Tags: git

Suppose I've got some software whose last released version is 1.1. Development from there has continued on two tracks:

- Normal updates on `master`
- Temporary changes meant to be released for a while as version 1.2, but not included in any subsequent versions. For example, imagine an `april_fools` branch.

My plan is to tag the temporary code as `v1.2` and release it, but **never merge it to master**. This is because if I did merge it:

- I'd have to to deal with merge conflicts
- Once all was resolved, I'd want to revert all of that temporary code anyway

Version 1.3 would be tagged and released based on the latest commit on `master` when the time came.

This seems like the cleanest solution, but I'm a little hesitant. **Should I worry about having a lineage of commits where versions 1.1 and 1.3 have no intervening commit tagged 1.2?** Could this cause confusion for later developers looking at the commit history?

Comment: I would be more confused by a merge of `1.2` back into trunk which was then subsequently reverted. Can you just not call it `1.2`? Call it `1.1_temporary_branch` or something?

Answer (score 2):

Your plan sounds best to me. If I were working on the repository and saw that v1.2 was skipped, it might make me wonder why, and I might make a note to look it up later, but it wouldn’t really stop me from doing any work at the time. I’ve used software with weird version numbering before, so I might just assume that it was some internal minor mess-up in the past.

For the curious developers, you could document “where is v1.2?” inside your project documentation – in your project wiki or `docs` folder or whatever. Though if your only documentation is a README, it’s probably not important enough to add at all.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

A tag is a reference to a commit in a DAG, and you don't really care about the history *continuity* of that graph.
You only care to get the exact content referenced by a tag.

If there is no merge between a branch with a tag 1.2 and master with 1.3, it emphasize a clear break in the development process (because of refactoring).

As long as the [semantic of the version number policy](http://semver.org/) is respected, (1.2 -> 1.3 full API compatibility), you are good to go.

Comment: I forgot: DAG=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Answer (score 2):

The longer the branches divert from each other, the worse the merging will be, if eventually you would be forced to do it later on.

In case the current mainline will be discarded later, all work done on it will go to waste. The longer this decision takes, the worse it will be. Bummer again.

Since it is a fork that is never intended to be merged back, don't tag it with `1.2`.
Give it a useful name, that would make you understand what happened there.

Even if you have no idea what changes occured. Make it idiot-proof. You now and you in half a year are not the same persons, knowledge-wise.